# Вызов fancybox в яндекс картах

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi, yandex-geocoding-api, yandex-maps-embed, yandex-places-api, yandex-static-maps-api

Как можно решить вопрос с вызовом `fancybox` по клику из балуна на яндекс картах? При клике на самой странице вызов обработчика работает, но при клике из яндекс карт нет.

```js
    $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
padding: 0,

                openEffect : 'elastic',
                openSpeed  : 150,

                closeEffect : 'elastic',
                closeSpeed  : 150,

                closeClick : true,

                helpers : {
                    overlay : null
                }
        
    });
  ymaps.ready(function() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('contactmaps', {
      center: [37.573856, 55.751574],
      zoom: 9
    }, {
      searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    }),
    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
      
      hintContent: 'Собственный значок метки',
      balloonContent: '<a href = "#zak" class="fancybox-media">Здесь не работает</a><br>'
    }, {
      iconImageHref: 'images/myIcon.gif',
      iconImageSize: [30, 42],
      iconImageOffset: [-5, -38]
    });

  myMap.geoObjects
    .add(myPlacemark)
    });
```

```css
.form {
  background: white
}

.modal {
  background: white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://voda-st.ru/local/assets/styles/common.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&coordorder=longlat&apikey=81c4db8d-b0b0-47d8-8c44-b237a0fd558c"></script>
<a href = "#zak" class="fancybox-media">Здесь работает</a><br>
  <div class="contacts__map-wrapper">
        <div id="contactmaps" class="contacts__map">
        </div>
    </div>
  <div id="zak" class="modal">
    <h4 class="modal__title">Заказать услугу</h4>
    <form action="index.html" method="post" id="zak-form" class="form">
                            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="*Ваше имя" class="form__input">
    
                            <input type="text" name="tel" placeholder="*Ваш телефон" class="form__input phone_mask">
                                <input type="text" name="serv" class="form__input servTypesa" disabled>

                        <input type="submit">
        </form>
</div>
```

пример
https://jsfiddle.net/yhs613n9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

использование jquery 2 версии помогло